# Modern, Non-trivial, Pygame Tutorials?

Tags: python, pygame

What are some 'good', non-trivial Pygame tutorials?

I realize good is relative.  As an example, a good one (to me) is the one that describes how to use [**pygame.camera**](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html). It's

- recent
- uses a modern PyGame (1.9)
- non-trivial, in that it shows how to use it the module for a real application.

I'd like to find others.  A lot of the ones on the Pygame site are from 1.3 era or earlier!

Info on related projects, like [Gloss](http://www.tuxradar.com/gloss) is welcome as well.

(If your answer is "read the source of some pygame games", please link to the source of particular ones and note what is good about them)

Answer (score 7):

(Shameless plug) - a 4-part [tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/category/programming/python/pygame-tutorial/) that starts [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/12/13/writing-a-game-in-python-with-pygame-part-i/). It builds a non-trivial 2D game-like simulation complete with quite a few features, using a modern version of Pygame.

[image]
<sub>(source: [thegreenplace.net](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/creeps_screenshot_4.png))</sub>

(**editor comment**:  In particular, this tutorial covers:

- the 'centering trick' for smoothing rotation
- simple animation
- AI pathfinding (using the A* algorithm)
- storing a 'grid map' to have obstacles on the game field
  )

Answer (score 1):

[Object oriented approach to PyGame](http://pygametutorials.wikidot.com)
The aim is to create 2D game engine, with classes that wraps PyGame.